# remove duplicates UNION ALL retrieved posts sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with `UNION ALL` clause to retrieve users posts.

```
SELECT * FROM $post WHERE condition 1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM $post WHERE condition 2
```

Results

```
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 3
Post 5
```

Expected

```
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3 (display only once)
Post 5
```

**PROBLEM**

How do I display only once a repeated post, when using `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION DISTINCT`, or just `UNION`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html says:

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal.

If your query must use `UNION ALL`, then make it subquery and use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM ( ...subquery... ) AS t
```

Comment: this is pretty clever, but for some reason, it doesnt work in my code, is there any other way to filter dupllicate rows? thank you

Comment: I don't know why this wouldn't work in your code, so I have no idea what else to suggest that might work.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `union`, because removes duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM $post WHERE condition 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM $post WHERE condition 2
```

The simpler and more efficient method is to use `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM $post
WHERE condition 1 OR condition 2
```